# Android. Prevent creating shortcut for application

Tags: android, shortcut, creation, homescreen

I have an appilcation with an intent filter for main activity

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

because I need an "Open" button in Play Market. But I don't want any shortcuts being created on homescreen or in application list.
How can I prevent creation of shortcuts, saving my "Open" button?

Comment: Did you try to remove <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> ?

Comment: Why would you want that.

Comment: There will be an OPEN button in playstore when someone install your app, even if you dont want it. But why you dont want a launcher . is it a live wallpaper. how will you trigger your app ..?

Comment: It's a decoration theme for an existig application. So I need this button to show user some instructions, but don't want to bother him with a useless icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `LAUNCHER` intent filter you have an Icon, there is no way around this. Keep the icon, no user will ever figure out that he has to navigate to the Playstore and then press open there. You can let the user hide the icon, there's an API for this.

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This might require a reboot